# update in procedure taking long time

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure Proc_1(P_IN_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2)
AS
CURSOR T_FACT
IS
SELECT T_ID,T_VER,D_T_ID
from O_T_FACT
where  T_ID is not null
and T_VER is not null;

TYPE call_tab IS TABLE OF O_T_FACT%rowtype;

BEGIN
   IF P_IN_TABLE_NAME ='G_FACT' THEN

   OPEN T_FACT;  
   LOOP 

      EXIT WHEN T_FACT%NOTFOUND ;   

            FETCH T_FACT BULK COLLECT INTO call_data_rec LIMIT no_of_rec;                   
            EXIT WHEN call_data_rec.count = 0;

                       FOR j IN 1..call_data_rec.COUNT
                        loop
                        UPDATE  G_FACT GL set
                        GL.T_ID = call_data_rec(j).T_ID, 
                        GL.T_VER =call_data_rec(j).T_VER,
                        GL.TRANS_FLAG='Y'
                        WHERE GL.G_T_ID = call_data_rec(j).D_T_ID
                        AND GL.T_ID IS NULL 
                        AND GL.T_VER IS NULL;             

                        rec_count := rec_count + 1;                       
                        if mod(rec_count,10000) = 0 then
                        commit;
                        end if;               
                        end loop; 

   end loop;
   CLOSE T_FACT;
   END IF;
End;
```

This particular procedure is taking long time, is there any other way to write this? Can this be done in a single update statement?

**As suggested below I have tired for all but its giving error as 
PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND table of records**

New Code with For all

```
create or replace procedure Proc_update_T_ID(P_IN_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2)
AS
no_of_rec number := 1000;
CURSOR T_and_V_FACT
IS
SELECT O_T_FACT.T_ID, O_T_FACT.T_VER, O_T_FACT.Downstream_T_ID, G_FACT.rowid row_id,
From O_T_FACT, G_FACT
WHERE O_T_FACT.T_ID IS NOT NULL AND G_FACT.G_T_ID = O_T_FACT.Downstream_T_ID
AND T_VER is not null
AND G_FACT.T_VER IS NULL;

TYPE call_tab IS TABLE OF T_and_V_FACT%rowtype index by binary_integer;
call_data_rec call_tab;

BEGIN
   IF P_IN_TABLE_NAME ='G_FACT' THEN
        IF T_and_V_FACT%ISOPEN THEN
            CLOSE T_and_V_FACT;
        END IF;    

        open T_and_V_FACT;

        LOOP

            FETCH T_and_V_FACT BULK COLLECT
            INTO call_data_rec LIMIT no_of_rec;

            FORALL j IN call_data_rec.FIRST .. call_data_rec.LAST    
            UPDATE  G_FACT GL set
                        GL.T_ID = call_data_rec(j).T_ID, 
                        GL.T_VER =call_data_rec(j).T_VER,
                        GL.TRANS_FLAG='Y'
            WHERE GL.rowid = call_data_rec(j).row_id;      

            COMMIT;                  
            call_data_rec.DELETE;
        EXIT WHEN T_and_V_FACT%NOTFOUND;      
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE T_and_V_FACT;
   End if;

END Proc_1;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) and what are the indexes on `G_FACT`?

Comment: CREATE INDEX GL_FACT_IDX05
ON EXAMIN_BI.GL_DTL_FACT(G_VE_DATE_KEY,G_T_ID,T_VER)

Comment: There are indexes on other column too, which are not part of this update statements.

Comment: try a `merge` into G_FACT using O_T_FACT. It is too simple.

Comment: I am using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit and similar script is running fine, what is the version of your Oracle server?

Comment: I think you are using oracle 8 or 9, I edited my answer to fit your Oracle version.

Comment: I m using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you could rewrite this into a single statement like so:

```
update G_FACT GL
set    (GL.T_ID, GL.T_VER, GL.TRANS_FLAG) = 
            (select T_ID,T_VER, 'Y'
              from   O_T_FACT F
              where  F.T_ID is not null
              and    F.T_VER is not null
              and    GL.G_T_ID = F.D_T_ID)
where  exists (select null
               from   O_T_FACT F
               where  F.T_ID is not null
               and    F.T_VER is not null
               and    GL.G_T_ID = F.D_T_ID)
and    GL.T_ID is null
and    GL.T_VER is null;
```

If this doesn't work, then you should be able to get significant gains by converting your `for` loop into a `forall` statement:

```
 FORALL j IN 1..call_data_rec.COUNT
    UPDATE  G_FACT GL set
    GL.T_ID = call_data_rec(j).T_ID, 
    GL.T_VER =call_data_rec(j).T_VER,
    GL.TRANS_FLAG='Y'
    WHERE GL.G_T_ID = call_data_rec(j).D_T_ID
    AND GL.T_ID IS NULL 
    AND GL.T_VER IS NULL;
```

Also, rethink whether you need that `commit` in the loop. Including this will:

- Slow your processing down
- Increase the chance of hitting ORA-1555s
- Possibly leave your data in an inconsistent state

Comment: Thanks a lot chris.. will try this on monday n will let u know... hv a grt a weekend

Comment: I m getting error for "For all" - PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND table of records.. I have added new code in question

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

Comment: I havent tired single update, also I have added new code in the question for the refernece

Comment: I m trying first update query, all logic in single update -  can you please tell why we need to use exists clause, I can see same query in earlier select.

Comment: The exists is to ensure you're only updating rows in `g_fact` that have a corresponding entry in `o_t_fact`. You could also write this an  `in` correlated subquery if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. but update statement made lot of difference.. procedure which used to take a almost a day is taking just 10 mins.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your CURSOR and hit UPDATE not in a loop statement
Also I prefer using `RowID` for update statements and `LIMIT` for fetch size of cursors and `FOR ALL`  for maximum performance and memory management.
We need to define a new type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_rec AS OBJECT
  ( T_ID NUMBER
  , T_VER number
  , row_id UROWID)
  );
```

Then using **Proc_1** may serve:

```
create or replace procedure Proc_1(P_IN_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2)
AS
no_of_rec number := 1000;
CURSOR T_and_V_FACT
IS
SELECT T_FACT.T_ID, T_FACT.T_VER, T_FACT.D_T_ID, G_FACT.rowid row_id,
  From O_T_FACT, G_FACT
 WHERE T_FACT.T_ID IS NOT NULL AND G_FACT.G_T_ID = O_T_FACT.D_T_ID
   AND T_VER is not null
      -- AND G_FACT.T_ID IS NULL -- not requierd
   AND G_FACT.T_VER IS NULL;

TYPE call_tab IS TABLE OF T_and_V_FACT%rowtype index by binary_integer;
call_data_rec call_tab;

BEGIN
   IF P_IN_TABLE_NAME ='G_FACT' THEN
   IF T_and_V_FACT%ISOPEN THEN
      CLOSE T_and_V_FACT;
   END IF;    
   open T_and_V_FACT;

 LOOP
      FETCH T_and_V_FACT BULK COLLECT
        INTO call_data_rec LIMIT no_of_rec;

      FORALL j IN call_data_rec.FIRST .. call_data_rec.LAST    
       UPDATE  G_FACT GL set
                        GL.T_ID = TREAT(call_data_rec(j) AS my_rec).T_ID, 
                        GL.T_VER =TREAT(call_data_rec(j) AS my_rec).T_VER,
                        GL.TRANS_FLAG='Y'
      WHERE GL.rowid = TREAT(call_data_rec(j) AS my_rec).row_id;      

      COMMIT;                  
      call_data_rec.DELETE;
      EXIT WHEN T_and_V_FACT%NOTFOUND;      
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE T_and_V_FACT;
   End if;
  END Proc_1;
```

I have edited some parts based on @Ben's comment. 
Also i did some changes based on [versions 9i and 10g](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=410) 
Restriction of using `TREAT` has been removed in 11g

Comment: You have a fair amount of unnecessary code here... There's no need to check if a locally defined cursor is open before opening it, you don't have to clear out the array, BULK COLLECT will overwrite for you. You're missing an END IF and I _think_ your exit statement is incorrect, I would normally check the count of the type after the fetch and exit if it's 0. You're doing some unnecessary work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks 4 your comment @Ben, I add the END IF statement, on CLOSE T_and_V_FACT; i have had problems when the transaction failed to commit and CURSOR remained open in some scenarios. call_data_rec.DELETE; may be unnecessary, but i do this by habit :)

Comment: m getting error for "For all" - PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND table of records.. I have added new code in question